# Assigning /32 ip addr to containers with docker compose Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04, macvlan

as you might quickly notice, I'm not a network nor a docker guru. I appreciate all help big time!

I'm trying to run a two applications in two different docker container using docker-compose. I managed to run 1 application using the host network. Great success, at least for half of my goal. Every container needs to be mapped to a specific IP address. If you wonder why, it's because the services in the containers will be accessed by other applications on the www on a specific port. But every container uses the same port for this communication. To give you a more visual idea of the desired setup, here's a visual:

[image: required network setup]

For service A I linked the container to the host network. My the docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  shell:
    image: "${MAIN_IMAGE}"
    container_name: mnm_shell
    network_mode: host
    pid: host
    volumes:
      - "mnms:/home/mnms"
    entrypoint: [ "bash" ]
    env_file:
      - "./.env"
```

After lots of research I found many articles describing how to make a macvlan with a private address subnet but I did not find any article describing how to link one (or more) /32 networks to specific containers.

Any help, guidance, examples are welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can set a specific host IP address with [`ports:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) and that's probably the easiest way to achieve this.  You do not want host networking, which pushes the address-assignment problem down to the application code.  (Of the Compose options you show, in fact, you can probably delete all of them except `image:` and `env_file:`.)

Comment: Tried that but I'm getting an error when I try to spin up the container: 2022-05-14T15:49:51.336537Z [api] ERROR crates/crash-handler/src/lib.rs:38 details = '''panicked at 'error binding to 50.50.50.199:8080: error creating server listener: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/warp-0.3.2/src/server.rs:213:27'''

Comment: The process inside the container doesn't need to know about the external host networking setup.  It needs to bind to 0.0.0.0 (or be very clever about inspecting the container-private network environment, but this isn't necessary).

Comment: Let me then put it differently, how do I run 2 databases that listen on the same port in docker? My host has 2 ip addresses and 2 Mac addresses? How I imagined it would work is as the picture shows… How do I configure such a setup? An example would be awesome… thx

Answer (score 0):

It's been 6 months since you posted, hopefully you will still find this useful.

You can do what your asking by creating a custom docker network which uses the `macvlan` driver. Relevant docker reference:
https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-macvlan/#bridge-example

First create the network:

```bash
docker network create -d macvlan \
  --subnet=50.50.50.0/24 \
  --gateway=50.50.50.1 \
  -o parent=eth0 \
  my-macvlan-network
```

Once created you can reference it in your docker-compose files. I've adapted your original example here:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

networks:
  my-macvlan-network:
    external: true

services:
  shell:
    image: "${MAIN_IMAGE}"
    container_name: mnm_shell
    networks:
      macvlan1:
        ipv4_address: 50.50.50.201
    volumes:
      - "mnms:/home/mnms"
    entrypoint: [ "bash" ]
    env_file:
      - "./.env"
```

**Note: `host` networking has been removed.**

A few things to note:

- You can have different containers/services using the same custom network with unique IP's.
- Any host on your network can access the `macvlan` IP's, however your docker host cannot. See the following link for a way to fix that:
  https://github.com/sarunas-zilinskas/docker-compose-macvlan#enable-host-to-container-networking

I'm using this technique on a linux host with PiHole and Gitea containers. Pihole wants port 53 (DNS) and gitea wants port 22 (SSH).